# Run a custom rake task on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am trying to make a custom `rake` task, but I cannot seem to get it working. My code looks like this:

```
namespace :demotask do

  desc "display the current environment of rake"
  task :current_environment => :environment do
    puts "You are running rake task in #{Rails.env} environment"
  end

end
```

and is placed in a file named `test.rake` under `lib/tasks`. The `Rakefile` is there, but I do get this error when running the task in the console:

> `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_environment' for main:Object`

I tried to restart the server as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `namespace` to call it from the terminal, and probably it's a good idea to use `bundler`:

```
bundle exec rake demotask:current_environment
```

Also, try to change task definition to:

```
task :current_environment => :environment do
...
```

Including `=> :environment` will tell Rake to load the full application environment.

Comment: Yes, of course I do use the namespace. Even with `bundler` I get the same error.

Comment: I tried using `=> :environment` but I get the same error nonetheless. Will modify my code with that.